# Error while viewing Cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, error

I am getting the error below while trying to view the cart page on my magento 1.9.3 shop.

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in ...
>   includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection.php on line **150**

Line 150 is this:

```
public function _addAssociatedProductFilters()
{
  $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts($this->getColumnValues('attribute_id'), $this->getProduct()); //Filter associated products
  return $this;
}
```

The error appears after certain simple products are added to the cart, but only if they are added last and usually only if the cart already contains configurable products. I tried re-creating the simple products, but it does not solve any problems.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried disabling compilation to see if it occurs when not compiled?

Comment: Yes, disabling compilation and clearing compilation data does not help